# Why does convolution of delta function commute (test distribution perspective)?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, distribution-theory, convolution, dirac-delta

If I understand correctly, for test functions $f$ we define

$$ \langle\delta, f\rangle = f(0)$$

and convolution is defined as

$$ \langle g * T, f\rangle = \langle T, g^- * f\rangle,$$

where $f$ and $g$ are test functions.

From this it follows that

$$ \langle g * \delta, f\rangle = \langle\delta, g^- * f\rangle = (g^- * f)(0) = \int g^-(-y) f(y) dy = \int g(y) f(y) dy = \langle g, f\rangle$$

so that $g * \delta = g$.

I don't see how any of this would imply that $
\delta * g = g$ as well. In fact, I don't even see how this expression makes sense, since $\langle \delta * g, f\rangle = \langle g, \delta * f\rangle $. Since $\delta$ is only defined as a distribution, I don't think $\delta * f$ has any meaning, let alone is a test function. Can someone clear this up for me?

Comment: TeX note: If you use \langle and \rangle for your brackets, it looks better. Compare $<\delta, f>$ to $\langle \delta, f\rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical definition of convolution of two arbitrary distributions with well associated supports is the following.

Let $S$ and $T$ be two distributions, respectively, with supports $A$ and $B$, and let $\varphi$ is a test function with support $K$. You define
$$
\langle S*T,\varphi\rangle=\langle S_x\otimes T_y,\alpha(x)\varphi(x+y)\rangle,
$$
where $\alpha$ is any test function that is equal to $1$ in a neighborhood of $A\cap(K-B)$. Then $S*T=T*S$ for any distributions with well associated supports.

Recall that two closed sets $A$ and $B$ are said to be well associated if $A\cap (K-B)$ is compact for any compact set $K$.

Comment: I'm not familiar with most of what you wrote. Do you have a good reference book? I am using https://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsoftaee261/book-fall-07.pdf

Comment: Yes, your "fourier" tags denounced that it might be the case. There are many advantages of looking at distributions as elements of the dual of test functions. My best recommendation are the 2 volumes by Laurent Schwartz "Théorie des distributions", I regret that I am not able to provide a better reference (that is actually published).

Answer (score -1):

To your question: Your definition of convolution is a map

$$ *:(\mbox{test functions})\times (\mbox{distributions})\to \mbox{distributions}. $$

So you're right, "$\delta * g$" does not make sense, as $\delta$ is not a test function.